# How do I add a tag to an answer?

Tags: support

I was about to post an answer in this weeks screen shot contest but, I can’t figure out how to add a tag to my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the syntax `[tag:tag-name]` to create a tag that links to the main site. For example, `[tag:starcraft-2]` will result in [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2)

If you need to link to a tag on the meta site, use `[meta-tag:tag-name]`, e.g. `[meta-tag:game-identification]` -> [game-identification](/questions/tagged/game-identification)